# How do I programmatically access single sprites when Sprite Mode is Multiple?

Tags: unity, sprites, spritesheet

Unity 4.3 newly brings an ability to cut up a sprite sheet into multiple individual sprites. This is useful since you then only need one master spritesheet, but nevertheless get references to individual sprites. It's done by setting *Sprite Mode* to *Multiple*.

Can all the sprites generated from the master file be programmatically accessed from the Unity Sprite Editor?

For example: I have a spritesheet with a grid of 50x50 sprites. Using the Unity Sprite Editor, I now have 250 sprites: `spritesheet_0, spritesheet_1, ..., spritesheet_249`. How can I get a handle to `spritesheet_102` without having to manually drag and drop it in the Unity editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a sprite array `Sprite[] sprites` and fill it using `sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Location");` inside Awake().

Comment: Also make sure all sprites are in Resources folder to use `Resources.LoadAll()`.